# Set the types of the args from `process.argv` in TypeScript, without type assertions

Tags: typescript, types, assert, argv, assertion

How can I, in TypeScript, set the types of the args passed in from `process.argv`, without using type assertions? Since using `as` would force the type, when I want to avoid that if possible.

What I have now:

```js
type AppName = 'editor' | 'terminal';

function main(args: string[]): void {
  const app: AppName = args[0] as AppName;
}

main(process.argv.slice(2))
```

What I want (pseudo-code):

```js
type AppName = 'editor' | 'terminal';

function main(args: string[]): void {
  // This doesn't actually work, since `in` doesn't work on `type`.
  if (!(args[0] in AppName)) {
    throw new Error("The first argument is not an app name.")
  }

  // The error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'AppName'.
  const app: AppName = args[0];
}

main(process.argv.slice(2))
```

Is anything similar to this possible? With the conditional, TS should detect that I have already ensured that the first arg is one of the given app names, and therefore accept setting it to a var with type `AppName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to use type guard. [Here's](https://medium.com/ovrsea/checking-the-type-of-an-object-in-typescript-the-type-guards-24d98d9119b0) an article on medium about it

I'm aware of that solution, but you may have something better available

```
type AppName = 'editor' | 'terminal';

function isAppName(toBeDetermined: any): toBeDetermined is AppName {
  if (toBeDetermined === 'editor' || toBeDetermined === 'terminal') {
    return true
  }
  return false
} 

function main(args: string[]): void {
  if (!isAppName(args[0])) {
    throw new Error("The first argument is not an app name.")
  }

  const app = args[0]; // const app: AppName
}
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAgmYDkCGBbaBeKByCATAlsAPYBOWUAPtsBCSvgHZIA2WA3AFAcBmArgwGNg+Igyj4AznESoIACmIAhCABEINOozwAuKEgYgAlLqWr1tegzziJseMjRQA3hyjjuUBUWVqNl6+iB2HiEpOQUVKa+Flq4UIGYWH6MLFiGzq5uUCTqvCRiwCS8EJkAvpk5wHli3CwSJaVQXHyCwqJQKEiMckgkAOYSuhKFjH0A2gC6xlAAbkT4cS5uAPTLUAAqABaSULhEEBIMSXpCvCzMIFAA7qQA1gA0UBKMAtAABoxvu-uHxzcktyg7TeoEgbwAdJl8B45ABCSTSBzyXoDMYABim6SWWWAmxIRCuUCshIAoiR8SQ5AAiLbQbj4EjDPT9XhoBjAGxEogc-R6eBE2TgqmGMpcFZrWlQWgU3TrcDQLDDEijcg7BjcvQSZ59JgAI2Y0GIUFBCsRsiwkLcAlETKQ-MwKIk6ImnHKQA) is a working playground for it